# How to set the style using a .jss file for a WebView in Titanium

Tags: webview, titanium

I would like to have a central place of defining the background color of a WebView in Titanium, but when I try to set this in the .jss file it does not work.

For example in my jss file I would have something like this, to set the style of a window, webview and label, but only the window and the label styles seem to apply.  Perhaps webviews are not supported in .jss files?

```
window {
    backgroundColor:'#222';
    barColor: '#28A700';
}

webview {
    backgroundColor:"#000";
}

label {
    color: '#eee';
    fontSize: '18px';

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Webview contain HTML. To set styles for background color you must styles in HTML file or link to CSS file from the HTML.

Comment: When you set the body background color in HTML or CSS it does not make the entire webView background that color from my testing.  It only makes the background immediately behind any text or elements that color.  To set the entre background color to a desired color I have found that I need to set backgroundColor when setting up the WebView.